# MediaWiki - Require confirmed emails before allowing read?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to setup a MediaWiki for university students. Using the [EmailDomainCheck](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EmailDomainCheck), I prevent anyone except those with a university based email from creating accounts. Using `$wgEmailConfirmToEdit`, I can require that an email is confirmed before the user can edit files. However, as it is, a user can use a fake email from the correct domain to create an account. With the account they can view all pages (even though they cannot edit them). I do not want to grant them read access unless the email has been confirmed. Is this possible? Note, I want all confirmed emails of the correct domain to be automatically accepted. It should not require manual account creation acceptance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following, as outlined in the [Documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights)

```
# Disable for everyone.
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
# Disable for users, too: by default 'user' is allowed to read, even if '*' is not.
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['read'] = false;
# Make it so users with confirmed email addresses are in the group.
$wgAutopromote['emailconfirmed'] = APCOND_EMAILCONFIRMED;
# Hide group from user list.
$wgImplicitGroups[] = 'emailconfirmed';
# Finally, set it to true for the desired group.
$wgGroupPermissions['emailconfirmed']['read'] = true;
```

As Jenny Shoars has mentioned, you may wish to whitelist some pages such as:

```
$wgWhitelistRead = array("Main_Page", "Special:CreateAccount", "Special:ConfirmEmail");
```

So that non registered users can still create accounts and the like.

Comment: I didn't do a lot of testing to check various cases of this yet, but this seems to work. However, others should note that you will probably need to whitelist a few pages, such as `$wgWhitelistRead = array("Main_Page", "Special:CreateAccount", "Special:ConfirmEmail");` to allow the users to get to the account creation page, and to confirm their email with the confirm email page.

Answer (score 1):

In theory,

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['emailconfirmed']['read'] = true;
```

should work. In practice, MediaWiki almost always used with an "everyone can read" or "you can read iff you are logged in" setup and others are not very well tested, so if that wiki had some highly sensitive private information I wouldn't do this, but I imagine for a university website that's not the case.

Alternatively, it should not be too hard to integrate an email confirmation step into account creation, but you'd have to write the code for that. [EmailAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EmailAuth) (which does a similar check during login) might give you an idea of how that would look.

Comment: Doesn't `*` only block non-logged in users, but still allow logged in but unconfirmed email users?

Comment: You need to override all fields in `$wgGroupPermissions` which enable reading and a new user could have them (the effective permission will be MediaWiki OR-ing together the `$wgGroupPermissions` sub-arrays for the groups you are a member of). You are right that that includes `user` as well by default.